# POSTing a ManagedObject via RestKit results in "Cannot update object that was never inserted"

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

I create a managed object save the context and post like so:

```
 [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:tag mapResponseWith:tagMappingForPOST delegate:tagLoader];
```

The `tagLoader` gets the object back but fails to save in the RestKit's context saying:

```
Failed to save managed object context after mapping completed: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134030.)

NSUnderlyingException=Cannot update object that was never inserted.
```

I'm doing the same thing with the same backend server (Parse.com) with the same class and it's working fine. Any clues as to the potential reasons why one would get a "Cannot update object that was never inserted." error?

Comment: How are you creating your tag object? I suspect it has never been inserted into your persistent store. Perhaps it is in a different thread/managed object context, perhaps it was created with init and not insert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out that RestKit expects the context to be saved *before* sending the `postObject:mapResponseWith:delegate` message to `RKObjectManager`. My issue was that I was saving the context right after the `postObject:mapResponseWith:delegate` message (which I thought was ok because this would still be before the loader ever got a response back from the webservice. I was doing something like so:

```
NSManagedObject *myObj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyObjects" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:myObj mapResponseWith:objMappingForPOST delegate:myObjLoader];
[context save:&error];
```

... then the `myObjLoader` would get a response back and attempt to update properties in `myObj` (createdAt, parse's objectId, etc.) and throw an error saying that myObj doesn't exist.

I should really read through the RestKit code to confirm, but I'm pretty sure what's happening is that `RKObjectManager` is creating the background thread and the context from the managed object store at the point in time the `postObject:mapResponseWith:delegate` message is received and never updates with any potential merges that might exists before the response comes back. To be honest, I expected the context to be created once the response was received.

So the thing to do is to save the context before sending the `postObject:mapResponseWith:delegate` message, like so:

```
NSManagedObject *myObj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyObjects" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[context save:&error];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:myObj mapResponseWith:objMappingForPOST delegate:myObjLoader];
```

Comment: This fixed my problem too. I looked through RestKits source and did not find anywhere that saves the context. Its funny though because this was not an issue until I started refactoring code. I think it may be a timing/synchronization issue also.

Comment: Thanks, I was using `save` inside `[context performBlock:]` without a need as I was already inside context block. I removed `performBlock` and it started to work.